# Fast way to delete many rows in a word-table using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

i'm trying to delete around 5k table entries in a word table with 2 columns.

The problem is, when I'm using

```
Function ClearTable(tbl As table)
Dim i As Integer

For i = tbl.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    tbl.Rows(i).Delete
Next i
    
End Function
```

it takes forever. I tried to just select the range from the cells (2,1) to (tbl.rows.count,2) and then use the .delete function, but that only empties the entries and does not remove the entire rows.

This issue seems kinda easy to handle, but I can't figure it out currently.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Update:

```
Function ClearTable(tbl As table)
Dim myCells As Range
Set myCells = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Start, _
            End:=tbl.Cell(tbl.Rows.Count, 2).Range.End)

myCells.Select
Selection.Rows.Delete

End Function
```

does what I wanted. Thanks to Timothy.

Comment: Did you try `Selection.Rows.Delete`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did really do the trick! Wondering why first it did not work, when I tried (or thought I tried it) this way. I now just select the range I wanted and then it works.

Comment: From the description in your question I suspect that you previously tried `Selection.Delete`

Comment: Yeah, I used that one and couldn't find the correct function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Selection is slow and unnecessary. All you need is:

```
Function ClearTable(Tbl As Table)
ActiveDocument.Range(Tbl.Rows(2).Range.Start, Tbl.Range.End).Rows.Delete
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. A friend also told me that this one line is the easiest. The "rows.Delete" was the trigger to get the correct function. Now it's fast and works as intended. Thanks a lot for the help.